# iOS insertObject with index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
self.messageArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[self.messageArray addObject:[[MessageData alloc] initWithMsgId:[_instantMessageID objectAtIndex:i] text:[_instantMessageData objectAtIndex:i] date:[NSDate date] msgType:JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing mediaType:JSBubbleMediaTypeText img:nil]];

[self.messageArray insertObject:[[MessageData alloc] initWithMsgId:[messageID objectAtIndex:i] text:[messages objectAtIndex:i] date:[NSDate date] msgType:JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing mediaType:JSBubbleMediaTypeText img:nil] atIndex:0];
```

First `addObject` part run and something add in my `self.messageArray` than when i run `insertObject` part again something add in my `self.messageArray` but not index 0.

This code part not work how can i fix this problem i want to add object always begin

For Example my first data : 
4,5,6,7,8

Second data : 1,2,3

I want to insert object begin like this {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Help please

Comment: That last line should in fact insert the data at the front of the array.... Could you be more specific about your current input and output?

Comment: Clarify "does not work". Your call to `insertObject` does put that object at index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `insert` is happening in a loop (that you haven't shown) hinted at by your usage of `i`. It is likely that you are looping over `i` in an increasing manner, but this will insert items to the beginning of your array in the reverse order that you desire.

You could solve this in one of two ways:

**Reverse your loop**

```
for (NSInteger i = numberOfObjects-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  [self.messageArray insertObject:obj atIndex:0];
}
```

**Use `i` as your insertion point**

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
  [self.messageArray insertObject:obj atIndex:i];
}
```